# How to know which TV remote is pressed in many of same remotes (Arduino)?

Tags: arduino, infrared

I have a ton of TV remotes. Is it able to know which one is pressed in many of same TV remote using arduino. I think it better to change the code of each remote but I do not know how to do that.
Thank you very much for helping me :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? If a remote weighs 100 grams then 1 ton of remotes will most probably be 10,000 remotes. If remote is pressed, its volume decreases, its count and weight remains same. if you update the code, its weight and quantity still remains same.

Comment: Also, if a remote is 20cm long, then 1 ton can be used to make a "remote line" of 2km.

Comment: with RTC No! You maybe missed a signal part and you can't decode it.

Comment: Unless you have special programmable universal remotes you're going to have to use different brands with different codes for each command. Think about it, TV's do not care which device the signal came from as long as it receives a valid code (to the TV, might be a 'trap representation' :p )... My AC remote on/off button changes my old TV's channel, simply same code was interpreted by the TV.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with regular method. Maybe you should add a res or a cap to change the HEX codes of TV remotes (to anything but different). I also think about using another way to press the buttons.